# One word for someone who doesn't care about anything

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

A *pessimist* is someone who always considers negative outcomes of a situation, whereas an *optimist* always considers the positive outcomes. Is there a word for someone who, in any given situation, doesn't care about the outcome at all?

Comment: Your title and the content of your question do not match up exactly: there is a difference between someone who, in a given situation, is indifferent to a certain outcome, and someone who _doesn’t care about anything_ at all. It would be helpful if you could add a more specific description denoting what type of ‘doesn’t-careness’ you are looking for, and whether you are looking for a neutral word, or one with either positive or negative connotations.

Comment: There are multiple dimensions to this (like any question about antonym or synonym). 'Realist' or 'pragmatist' are as yet unmentioned.

Comment: According to most wives, the word would be **husband**.

Comment: On YouTube, this would be a [Honey Badger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r7wHMg5Yjg).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I can't think of a noun, but you can say "that person is apathetic".

[Apathetic](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apathetic?q=apathetic) at Oxford Dictionaries

> *adjective* showing or feeling no interest, enthusiasm, or concern

Comment: Perhaps an "apathete?"  "Apathist" is listed below also.

Comment: Ooh, I'll add 'apathetor' and 'apathetician'. @JackRyan

Answer (score 34):

***Indifferent***
<sub>http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=indifferent</sub>

> late 14c., "unbiased," from Old French indifferent "impartial" or
>   directly from Latin indifferentem (nominative indifferens) "not
>   differing, not particular, of not consequence, **neither good nor evil**,"
>   [...] Extended sense of
>   "apathetic" first recorded early 15c.; that of "neither good nor bad"
>   1530s, on notion of "**neither more nor less advantageous**."

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a noun, as the OP requests. . .

Comment: @JackRyan  But it does describe a person in one word, and it fits the "doesn't care about the outcome at all" criteria.

Answer (score 29):

This might not be quite what you are looking for, but as an extreme case:

[**Nihilist**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nihilistic).

This stems from following *nihilism* (adapted from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/)):

> 1. Total rejection of prevailing religious beliefs, moral principles, laws, etc., often from a sense of despair and the belief that life is devoid of meaning.
> 2. The belief or theory that the world has no real existence; the rejection of all notions of reality.

A nihilist would not care about an outcome because it is entirely meaningless.

The word has some negative connotations from meaning 1 above, which may make it unsuitable for your particular purpose.

Answer (score 24):

A *fatalist*. This does not just mean a person who thinks all things are fated; it has a derived meaning: a person with an attitude of indifference to outcome because of such a belief. An *optimist* hopes for the best; a *pessimist* fears the *worst*; a *fatalist* is resigned to what will be (regardless of hopes and fears). http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fatalism

Comment: Although this person in question doesnt beleive in fate either. he just doesn't care

Answer (score 22):

**Insouciant**

> free from concern, worry or anxiety
>
> Unconcerned, undisturbed; carefree and nonchalant
>
> Origin:
> 1820–30;  < French,  equivalent to in- in-3  + souciant  present participle of soucier  to worry < Vulgar Latin *sollicītāre,  for Latin sollicitāre  to disturb; see solicitous

as suggested in the definitions the other words I would prefer to use are:

***nonchalant***

***unconcerned***

All of these words imply a carefree attitude in a good way and lack the negative connotations of having no feeling at all.

Comment: I like *nonchalant* better than *insouciant*. I'm glad your dictionary entry gave a couple other good suggestions (_unconcerned_ isn't bad, either); it saved me from having to write my own answer.

Comment: Yes I entirely agree. 'Insouciant' was the first word that sprang to mind. I think all three have the same connotations and I would prefer either of these to the other suggestions - because the others have predominantly negative connotations.

Comment: Good points, although I don't necessarily see *indifferent* as predominantly negative (I suppose it depends on the situation – being "indifferent" to starving children would be negative, being "indifferent" about leaving your sandwich at home would not). Isn't it commonly asked: _"How do you feel about that? Good, bad, or indifferent?"_ Seems I've heard that multiple times before. All the answers so far, though, show how hard it is to really give the O.P. what's being asked for: a noun that describes the person. Adjectives abound, but that single noun appears elusive.

Comment: +1 Insouciant is one of the few nouns listed amongst answers.

Answer (score 22):

In modern Internet parlance, such a person might be referred to as a **"honey badger"**:

[image: he honestly doesn't care.]

This use of the term is based on [this popular youtube video](http://youtu.be/4r7wHMg5Yjg).

(Hat tip to user @balpha for bringing this oversight to my attention.)

Answer (score 13):

1-[Unresponsive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unresponsive?showCookiePolicy=true)

2-[Detached](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/detached?showCookiePolicy=true)

3-[Disinterested](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disinterested?showCookiePolicy=true)

4-[Oblivious](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oblivious?showCookiePolicy=true)

Answer (score 11):

That would be an apathist I think.

Answer (score 9):

[Carefree](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/carefree)- having no worries

On the day of the result, Ajay, being optimistic, was very sure of securing all the A grades. But Arun's pessimistic mind was busy looking for excuses to tell his parents why he flunked this time. And Aakash remained as **carefree** as ever and kept playing video games throughout the day.

Answer (score 5):

How about "this person is a stoic" ?

According to [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic?show=0&t=1378636983):

> Definition of STOIC ... 2
>   : one apparently or professedly indifferent to pleasure or pain

Comment: its actually indifference to the outcome, not the perception of the outcome

Comment: Stoicism refers to someone who will bare discomfort without complaint not someone who cares not a jot about the outcome.

Answer (score 5):

How about the adjective related to the word:

**Acedia**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acedia

Does such an adjective exist in English by the way ??

**acedious**, adj.
http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/previous-updates/december-2011/new-words-list/

Comment: The great poet Dante Alighieri dedicated en entire section (18-th) of the hell to the people who were so  :-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UknDVBt-Eg

Answer (score 2):

Technically one could say a realist. However this probably isn't applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

A person who cares not at all about anything "in any given situation", must surely be...a **cadaver**.

More seriously, there are also **mugwumps**, **sloths**, and **bumps-on-a-log**, all of which have some of the qualities you describe.

Comment: Good joke, but I'm casting my upvote for "bump on a log."

Answer (score 0):

(1)Selfish 
A man who doesn't care about anything must clearly be the most self absorbed person on the earth. And if he is not self absorbed then refer to answer #2
(2)Dead

Comment: Well, this would apply on a different context. OP wants something in the middle of pessimism-optimism spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

Insouciant is a word in both the French and English language for a person who does not care about anything. In French it can be both an adjective & a noun. I don't see why one could not use it as a noun in English too. Such a person would be an insouciant. Such an noun is needed.

Answer (score 0):

From MW - **indifferent**

1a
: marked by a lack of interest, enthusiasm, or concern for something : APATHETIC
indifferent to suffering and poverty

b
: marked by no special liking for or dislike of something
indifferent about which task he was given

2
a
: being neither good nor bad : MEDIOCRE
does indifferent work

b
: being neither right nor wrong

3
: being neither excessive nor inadequate : MODERATE
hills of indifferent size

4
: marked by impartiality : UNBIASED

5
a
: that does not matter one way or the other

b
: of no importance or value one way or the other.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for one who not only doesn't care about anything, but is in a general surly mood about things...there's "Misanthrope", and the adjective form, "Misanthropic".

Comment: Except that "misanthrope" is not a surly person or a person who doesn't care about anything. It is a person who hates mankind.

Comment: True...I have seen it used without explicitly meaning a hatred towards mankind, but we should try to encourage the use of the proper definition anyway.  A misanthrop might still be surly, but then again, they might cheerfully despise all of humanity just as well.