# Word for not caring at all about anything

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

I've looked at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125868/one-word-for-someone-who-doesnt-care-about-anything)  but it doesn't quite match the term I'm seeking.

I once heard a speaker use a term to describe the syndrome accompanied with drug dependencies. He said the word and then asked if anyone knew what it meant. His personal interpretation of the meaning of the word was something like, "...***the feeling that the world could fall apart around me and I wouldn't care*** so long as I have my fix." He went on to give other examples such as, "...***I don't care how the bills get paid***, I need my (insert drug of choice)."

I'm trying to find what the word is for this. [Apathetic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apathetic) and [indifferent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/indifferent) are not it.(though apathetic is close)

It's not just emotional, or physical, or psychological... it's all of these. Basically, almost like a catatonic state of *being*. Also, and I don't know if this helps anyone other than me, if you can imagine Eeyore from Winnie the Pooh saying, "In the long run, we all die. What would be the point of living? Why do *anything* when it all ends the same way?"

The way this term could be used in a sentence would be,

> It's pointless talking to Mark right now, he's fallen victim *to/to his* ______

Update: Okay, I found this from [submissivesuccubus.blogspot.com](http://submissivesuccubus.blogspot.com/2010/08/truth.html) (don't ask), *"When the three of us are together, I feel as if the world could fall apart around me and I wouldn't care at all."*

Now this example has a positive connotation to it. I'm looking for the negative.

**Last Update:**
Okay, one more example before I give into *nihilism*. If I'm sitting at my house, normal night, watching TV, and then a tow truck pulls up and begins to tow my car. I notice, but don't care or do anything about it. Then the phone rings, I don't answer because I don't care. The power goes out, I don't do anything. I sit in the dark now staring at the wall. An earthquake occurs, I don't move. The house falls apart around me. I still sit in the rubble. I don't care. Bulldozers plow away the debris around me. Winter sets in. WWIII, zombie apocalypse, a black hole swallows the Earth and I don't move, don't care.
I've lost something. Something that makes me pay the power bills, something that makes me get up and hide from zombies... I am/ have become/ have __________ If you tell me that *nihilism* works for this, than I will concede to it (though it's not the word I was looking for) You all are AWESOME-sauce in my book and I appreciate the efforts.

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)

Comment: "What's up with Dave? He's been lying on the couch for three days. He won't talk to me. I don't think I've even seen him eat." "Forget it, man, he's *checked out*."

Comment: It's a little more of a 'technical' term. Thanks though.

Comment: [Insouciant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insouciance)? [Nonchalant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonchalant)?

Comment: You will find all the synonyms here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/apathetic but I do not think this is what you are looking for. Apathetics usually do not care about anything, here the guy is very enthusiastic about finding the drug money, so "apathy" is not the right word here.

Comment: @LordSoth No, and forgive me, I tried to emphasize the part of the sentence that applies. "...so long as I have my fix." is not part of the term I'm looking for.

Comment: what about ennui ...

Comment: IMO it's very unclear what you mean. Is the person a prick because they only care about "getting theirs"? Is the person sad, "given-up" feeling?  or what?  it's just totally unclear dude, sorry.

Comment: No I understand the convolution. It's not about a feeling (sad/given up), it's not about a motivation (getting theirs), it's simply a state one would find themselves (for example's sake) after a trauma or as a side-effect of depression. There's no feelings, at all.

Comment: Nihilism as a philosophy is very far away from your original description. Nihilism as a once (still?) over-used fashion term was once of the "philosophies" of _punk_. And now it means something "close to apathy"? Camus is turning in his grave...

Comment: The other really good one I saw was anhedonia. My problem is that from what I can remember, the term I remember hearing as a 'an'word....

Comment: Maybe the term you have in mind is Ataraxia (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataraxia ), which is sometimes used (spuriously) in its Stoic connotation to describe the state of detachment you describe.

Comment: @MegaMark: How about "ambivalent"? It's basically a word that says you don't care either way about things.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Ambivalent doesn't (imho) carry with it a negative connotation...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're asking in a psychological context, are you looking for one of:

> ***Detachment*** (*detached*)
>
> ***Dissociation*** (*dissociated*)
>
> ***Depersonalization*** (*depersonalized*)
>
> ***Emotional numbness*** (*numb*)

---

Based on the updated question, perhaps you're looking for:

> ***Nihilism*** (*nihilistic*): Nihilism is often discussed in terms of extreme skepticism and relativism; for most of the 20th century it has been associated with the **belief that life is meaningless**. Existential nihilism begins with **the notion that the world is without meaning or purpose**. Given this circumstance, **existence itself–all action, suffering, and feeling–is ultimately senseless and empty**.

From [the Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on Nihilism](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nihilism/), though there are plenty of other choices (e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihilism#Existential_nihilism)).

Comment: It's something more along the lines of *all* of these things... see my edit.

Comment: If you mean "the utter pointlessness of being", are you looking for "*nihilistic*"?

Comment: More like the nihilistic of EVERYTHING... not just societal beliefs and ethics etc. But nothing is worth anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's nihilism.  Nihilism is the absolute rejection of everything.

Comment: When I looked at the definition, it seemed like this word was tied to politics...?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_disorder

Comment: No, Nihilism is a philosophy that rejects *everything* as meaningless; that nothing has value (whether that's morals, politics, life, or seashells). See my updated answer and links.

Comment: Okay, I like it. But would you ever say, "Mark has once again fallen victim to nihilism *or (his nihilism)*"? Oh, and when you say that Nihilism is a philosophy... that kind of pulls it out of the box I'm looking for. The term isn't a direct choice of anything (like following a philosophy) but more of an indirect side-effect of... something, say for example trauma or depression.

Comment: A philosophy just means "a way of seeing the world" or "a way of framing reality". It's not restricted to tweeded professors arguing over Wittgenstein: everyone subscribes to a philosophy, (even if he doesn't know it), and those philosophies can be used as descriptors: "Man, Joe is a real *nihilist*", "Ever since his mom died, Dave has been in a *nihilistic funk* ", etc.

Comment: Or, perhaps a more pertinent example:  A 1996 article in the Los Angeles Times was covering the then-trending style "**heroin chic**", *describing* it as "a **nihilistic vision of beauty**": http://articles.latimes.com/1996-08-08/news/ls-32243_1_fashion-industry

Comment: I am actually surprised that _nihilism_ seems to fit the bill. Not what Camus had in mind at all. Well, another stolen word :)

Answer (score 6):

The most proper word would be:

> nihilism
>
> n [U] [Date: 1800-1900; Language: German; Origin: nihilismus, from
>   Latin nihil 'nothing']//
>    1 the belief that nothing has any meaning
>   or value:
>   2 the idea that all social and political institutions
>   should be destroyed

Comment: Can you please site your source? When I looked for the definition, I only found entries that are tied to politics/societal views and ethics and such... can this be used in a broad, generalized way? "It's no use talking to him, Mark has fallen victim to nihilism"?

Comment: it's very commonly used in a broad generalised way.  simply google for written uses. "teenage nihilism..."

Comment: Reference material copied from elsewhere (which this appears to be, given that it's quote-formatted) [**must** have a citation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) in plain-text indicating its origin. Please add one, or this answer may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

The condition you are describing is *ennui*, "a feeling of utter weariness and discontent resulting from satiety or lack of interest; boredom" ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ennui)). Ennui is boredom on steroids, dissatisfaction taken to an existential level. Oddly, the *Oxford English Dictionary* reports that *ennui* can be used as a transitive verb as well—"to affect with ennui; to bore, weary"—although all of its examples are from the 19th century. The adjectival form *ennuying* is also listed, but described as "rare."

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like the condition known as [anhedonia](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anhedonia). The term is more common in medical / psych settings but you do hear it elsewhere.

Comment: YES!!!! Excellent!!!! But it's not *just* pleasure that cannot be experienced... I do think either this or nihilism was the word the speaker used... I wish I could mark multiple answers...

Answer (score 4):

I'd never seen this splendid word until today, but I feel compelled to bring it to the public's attention:

From Merriam-Webster:

> **[pococurante](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pococurante)** - *adjective \ˈpō-kō-kyu̇-ˈran-tē* meaning *indifferent, nonchalant*.  From the Italian for "caring little"

It may have found its origin, capitalised, as a character in Voltaire's *Candide*.

There's a lovely non-capitalised usage in an [essay on Lord Melbourne](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1vbii31mPK0C&pg=PA255&dq=%22pococurante%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WBjqU4mAIK7E4gSt-4CYDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22pococurante%22&f=false), by Abraham Hayward, published in 1858.

> … during many years he apparently led a careless, indolent, *pococurante* life, divided between the gay circles of London and the House of Commons.

Comment: It seems to have a more positive connotation than what the OP describes, though. More like _happy-go-lucky_.

Comment: Just added a link to M-W online definition

Comment: I don't know how to explain why, but there's something amiss about this word. Though, EXCELLENT word find!!!! Nonchalant and indifferent really don't get the explicit tone/connotation that comes with the word I'm looking for. +1 for the find!

Answer (score 2):

[Lethargic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lethargic) comes to mind.

Merriam-Webster says:

> 2 :  indifferent, apathetic

So it encapsulates both of the ones you mentioned, but the first description is:

> 1 :  of, relating to, or characterized by laziness or lack of energy :  feeling or affected by lethargy :  sluggish

The lack of energy, laziness, seems to relate to the drug dependency you describe.

Comment: Lethargic seems to have a physical connotation to it though, and that would only encompass part of the effect. It's also a very mental effect/attitude. And keep in mind, the drug dependency example is just one of many examples. This term is not directly dependent on drug use. I would almost venture to say that lethargy is a side-effect of the word I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, _laziness_ is usually rather mental than physical (tiredness being the physical version), so I think the description _does_ encapsulate both mental and physical effects... But I am puzzled and hoping to be surprised by the word you _are_ looking :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess [alienated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Alienated) may convey the idea  of feeling lost   and indifferent  to life that  you describe:

> - withdrawn or unresponsive; isolated or dissociated emotionally.

[Feeling of Alienation in Recovery:](http://alcoholrehab.com/addiction-recovery/feelings-of-alienation-in-recovery/)

> - Addicts will often describe themselves as being outsiders in society. Even before they tuned to substance abuse they may have experienced discomfort around other people – a feeling that they just did not fit in.

You may be referring also to a feeling of *self-destruction* as a consequente of drag  abuse:

[self-destructive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Self-destructive):

> - 1. Tending to do harm to oneself.
>   2. Marked by an impulse or tendency to harm or kill oneself.

Comment: Yes, but again remember this term is not confined to the use case of drug use. It's a more generalized (yet specific, and yes I know that sounds like an oxymoron) term. And it's not just a societal withdrawl.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly to me, no one has mentioned [feckless](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/feckless). While it has connotations of being *ineffectual*, which the person in your question is even if by accident, the [origin of it](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=feckless) is a Scottish word *feck*, meaning "effect, vigor, value" -- three things your hypothetical despondent character lacks. The dictionary entry for it also supports this usage:

> 1. Lacking purpose or vitality
> 2. Careless and irresponsible

Answer (score 1):

In light of your recent edit(and apart from my previous suggestions)-

> Update: It's not just emotional, or physical, or psychological... it's
>   all of these. Basically almost like a catatonic state of being. Also,
>   and I don't know if this helps anyone other than me, if you can
>   imagine Ior from Winnie the Poo saying, "In the long run, we all die.
>   What would be the point of living? Why do anything when it all ends
>   the same way?"

I would recommend: **despondent**

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/despondent):

> **despondent** *adjective*
>
> very sad and without hope

Like the usage of despondent here:

- Writers who spend much time in universities are likely to grow **despondent** over the future of literature, for there it is treated as a finished thing. —Louis Simpson, New York Times Book Review, 21 Nov. l982

Comment: Yes but no, this word, like despair, is tied to emotion. The term I'm looking for is not... I really wish I could explain it better. I feel that I'm at fault for not properly being able to explain. Again thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the terms  *[affectless](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/affectless)* (Collins: “showing no emotion or concern for others; not giving rise to any emotion or feeling”) and  *[anomie](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anomie#Noun)* (Wiktionary: “Alienation or social instability caused by erosion of standards and values”).

*[Affect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affect_%28psychology%29)* is a psychological term referring to experience of feeling and emotion.  An affectless person, or one with *[flat affect](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/flat+affect)* or *[blunted affect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blunted_affect)* does not react normally in emotional situations.

According to [thefreedictionary.com](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/flat+affect), flat affect is

> the absence or near absence of emotional response to a situation that normally elicits emotion. It is observed in schizophrenia and some depressive disorders.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blunted_affect), blunted affect

> is the clinical term describing a lack of emotional reactivity (affect display) on the part of an individual. It manifests as a failure to express feelings either verbally or non-verbally, especially when talking about issues that would normally be expected to engage the emotions.

Answer (score 0):

**Energy**

- lethargy
- exhaustion
- weary

**Drive/Will**

- purposeless
- aimless
- disinterested

**Emotional**

- stoic: a person who accepts what happens without complaining or showing emotion ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic))
- depressed (Depression is both common and sensitive, so [understand](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/basics/definition/con-20032977) it and use it considerately.)
- dispassionate
- melancholic

**Empty**

- hollow
- soulless
- vacant
- bereft

**Focus**

- neglectful
- single-minded

**Unmoving**

- catatonic
  2
  :  characterized by a marked lack of movement, activity, or expression ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catatonic))
- impassive
- neutral
- inert
- torpid: having or showing very little energy or movement : not active

  a :  having lost motion or the power of exertion or feeling :  dormant, numb

  b :  sluggish in functioning or acting

  2
  :  lacking in energy or vigor :  apathetic, dull

  ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/torpid))

Answer (score -2):

I would say:

- ignorance
- indolence

Comment: Why? Please review the guidelines on how to provide useful answers in the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score -2):

What about the word apathetic? It certainly pertains, but it doesn't really capture the importance of the fix since someone who was apathetic could be expected not to care about the fix either.

Comment: *Apathetic* is specifically mentioned as being not the word.

Answer (score -2):

most of the discussion here is centered around the negative connotations - there could also be equivalents on the Zen side i.e. unperturbed state in the face of adversity.

Not entirely sure if it classifies here but my teacher used to mention ATARAXIA to indicate serenity.

According to the website, www.john-uebersax.com, 
ATARAXIA pertains to "imperturbability, freedom from disturbance, equipoise, tranquility"

Merriam Webster describes it as "calmness untroubled by mental or emotional disquiet "

john-uebersax.com/plato/words/ataraxia.htm

Comment: You should check some reliable resources and mentioning them in your answer rather than referring to what just your teacher said.

Comment: Fair enough, Neeku. My apologies for that. According to the website, www.john-uebersax.com, ATARAXIA pertains to "imperturbability, freedom from disturbance, equipoise, tranquility"
Merriam Webster describes it as "calmness untroubled by mental or emotional disquiet "
http://www.john-uebersax.com/plato/words/ataraxia.htm

Comment: @Viqar my comment was to help you improve your answer. You should edit your post and add the info there to make it a better answer.