# A word for not caring

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to convey an concept that the world cannot possibly care one way or the other.

> Karma does not exist. Society is *neutral* it doesn't care either way about what happens with your life. You are the only person who controls it.

I once hears such a word but I forgot it.

Comment: related [One word for someone who doesn't care about anything](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125868/one-word-for-someone-who-doesnt-care-about-anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest

**indifferent** - having no particular interest or sympathy; unconcerned.

Answer (score 3):

**unsympathetic** should also do the trick.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Karma does not exist. Society is apathetic it doesn't care either way about what happens with your life. You are the only person who controls it.

I think you're looking for apathetic